# logstash-elasticsearch: sort data by timestamp

Tags: sorting, logging, logstash

I centralize logfiles into one logfile by using logstash and for each event I have timestamp(the original one).
Now, my last challenge it to get this data sorted by timestamp(if possible on real-time thats better).

my timestamp format is: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Now, I can make any change in the format/ file format in order to make it work, as long as it stays on our servers.

What's the best way to sort my data?
any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you're basically asking how to sort a text file? Or what, exactly, do you want Logstash to do?

Comment: I prefer to use logstash for that because sorting a txt file an take long time. Update: if elasticsearch will be useful for that, I can use it.

Comment: If events arrive in the correct order Logstash can just write them to disk and they will be sorted. But what if events arrive out of order? What is Logstash supposed to do? Keep messages in memory for a while and periodically flush them to disk in the correct order to accommodate for some out of order messages? If you can use Elasticsearch, do it. Logstash doesn't store log events.

Comment: thanks @Magnus Bäck .In addition- any way for logstash output into mysql db?

Comment: I don't think there's any direct support for MySQL but you can run a program for each message or pass message off to a simple TCP server that inserts into MySQL, or ship to a message broker (Redis, RabbitMQ, ...) that a simple service can pull messages from and insert into MySQL. There are many options.