# Sort logs based on timestamp in original logs using elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, timestamp, logstash

I am using logstash+elasticsearch to index server logs. The logs if of this format:
**17/03/15-06:29:30 31609 453749 545959 1 4 http://www.somesite.com/index.html - 0**

Here is my logstash config file:

```
filter {
  grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} %{NUMBER:some_id} %{NUMBER:some_id} %{NUMBER:some_id} %{NUMBER:some_id} %{NUMBER:some_id} %{DATA:url} %{GREEDYDATA:log_message}" }
    }  
  date {
    match => ["timestamp", "dd/MM/YY-HH:mm:ss"]
    #remove_field => ["timestamp"]
  }
  mutate {
    remove => [ "message" ]
  }
}
```

I want to sort logs using the timestamp string of the logs. I have tried with and without using the 'date' filter. But unfortunately I am not able to query the timestamp field, sort or do a range query.

What should I do to make timestamp field sortable and queryable?
Is there a way to do this? Can anyone please help me with this situation? please comment if I am not clear with my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `@ankit.vic`  Is it logs are loaded into `Elasticsearch` ???

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188847/logstash-elasticsearch-sort-data-by-timestamp

Comment: @AnilkumarBathula I could not find the answer in the link provided and yes logs are loaded into elasticsearch.

Comment: If events arrive in the correct order Logstash can just write them to disk and they will be sorted. But what if events arrive out of order? What is Logstash supposed to do? Keep messages in memory for a while and periodically flush them to disk in the correct order to accommodate for some out of order messages? If you can use Elasticsearch, do it. Logstash doesn't store log events..

Comment: Already `timestamp` filed data is sorted defaultly,when the logs are loaded. If you need clear clarification you need to see in `Kibana UI`

Comment: I am using the `head` plugin in ES and when I try to sort the `timestamp` field, the results are not correct. while when I use `date` filter and map **timestamp to @timestamp** and try to sort using @timestamp, the results are  as expected. I do not understand this. Plus why am I not able to query the `timestamp` field ?

Answer (score -1):

See the below image of logs are loaded on the sorting base...

[image: Time Stamp in Kibana UI]

Comment: Thank you Anilkumar. I also had some doubts regarding querying the timestamp field. For example: `curl 'localhost:9200/_count?q=**some_id:3196**&&pretty'` gives me perfect count of the number of docs I have in my indexes. but why cannot I query the **timestamp** field. I am sorry if my doubts are silly. I am very new to logstash + elasticsearch.

Comment: I am getting this error  **` "BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[logstash-2015.07.27][1] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[logstash-2015.07.27] Failed to parse query [time_stamp:18/*]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse 'time_stamp:18/*': Lexical error at line 1, column 16.  Encountered: <EOF> after : \"/*\"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 16.  Encountered: <EOF> after : \"/*\"]; "
`**